# iOS app rejected IPv6 (without any http request)

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, appcelerator, ipv6

I've an iOS app that was rejected due the IPv6 incompatibility.

I've tested with a shared IPv6 network from my MacBook Pro, and works fine.

I don't have any http request or connection in my app, the only 2 present url's are placed in the app description and they are 2 labels (without any click event).

I'm developing using Appcelerator Studio (SDK v5.1.1) with xcode 8 and testing on iPhone 5S (v10.1.1).

**There were my steps:**

- Build in Appcelerator Studio 4.8.0 with 6.0.0.GA SDK
- Removed the tiapp.xml ACS properties and removed ti.cloud also
- Run the app on iPhone 5S Simulator with 10.1.1 (without liveview)
- Open the generated project in xcode (myApp/build/iphone/myApp.xcodeproj)
- Select Build Only Device: iOS Generic Device
- Product > Archive
- Validate... -> OK
- Upload to App Store... -> OK

I've also compiled to iTunes Sync (ipa file only to registered devices) in order to install on my iPhone 4 and iPhone 5S and it works fine

**I'm using 2 Titanium modules:**

- [com.mikefogg.squarecamera](https://github.com/mikefogg/SquareCamera)
- [ti.light](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.Light)

None of this modules have an http request.

**Message from iTunes Connect:**

```
Hello,

Performance - 2.1


Thank you for your resubmission. However, we still discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on an iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.1.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, an error was encountered upon application launch.

We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.
```

[image]

Comment: What does the screenshot show?

Comment: could not find the file app.js (after compiling the Appcelerator project built in Alloy, it converts to the default js project style and generates that file)

Comment: It looks the the IPv6 thing is a bit misleading. Your app isn't packaged correctly. Apple just mentions that they experience the issue on an IPv6 wifi network but it looks like it would have a problem on any network.

Comment: But I don't have any feature in the app that require an internet connection, just the ti.cloud module, but I don't know if as anything to do with this. I'll remove the ti.cloud module and recompile the app with the 6.0.0.GA that came out yesterday, but still, I don't know how to find the source of this error

Comment: I understand. That is why I say that I think Apple mentioning IPv6 is misleading. From the looks of your screen shot your app is failing because of a packaging problem; it can't find the app.js file. The error message also indicates that you shouldn't see that message at all in a final,distribution package.

Comment: I'm submitting again the project, I've updated my steps on my question

Comment: I've also removed all the acs properties at the tiapp.xml and ti.cloud

Comment: I've received the same rejected message, I don't know where to begin with :/ it's the most simple app that I've made without any network connection, should have something to do with the modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't IPv6 but your app is not packaged correctly. To solve the problem you must have an active license (Indie, Pro, Team or Enterprise) and in "Appcelerator Studio" you must select "package" -> "iOS iTunes Store" for a correctly distribution.

[image]

Otherwise you'll have the app.js error because the app is not packaged for final distribution.

Comment: Thank you, I was sending the xcodeproj file that is generated after building an app, in my case, I've use the iTunes Sync, I'll try to package for iTunes Store, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

BE SURE THE APPLE REVIEWER IS USING YOUR APP CORRECTLY, THEY DIDN'T WITH MINE.... THERE WAS/IS NO IPV6 ISSUE!

Just a note, but my app was rejected for IPv6 network issue on a iPad with iOS 10.3.2, turns out the Apple Reviewer had not set a record time on my Video/Audio Record app (#PCAMWBUMS) and if you don't set a record time, my app does nothing!

So read the note Apple Review sends you and be sure they haven't made a mistake before you do all the research and waste time, when it turns out they just read your App Guide and clearly marked notes on the boot up screen!  (Which they didn't.)

So I've replied to ask them to set a record time and try again, which I have tested on my iPad Air and iPhone 6S Plus both running iOS 10.3.2... I'm sure they'll pass my app and release it to the app store (which all of you should download, to catch those celebs, or anitifa, or thieves using your iPad, iPhone, or iPod Touch (or the unfaithful partner?), visit JOHNAVATAR.com to see all my apps)!

For some reason they sent me the following rejections notice:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone
>   and iPad running iOS 10.3.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, there is no action produced when tapping the buttons on
>   the main page.